# How to send a job/http request in Java(with json) to a webservice which has a submit button?

Tags: java, json, web-services, soap, httprequest

I want to send a http request from my java programm to the [NetMHC](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/services/NetMHC/) webservice as its results are part of my pipeline. I put my sequence into a json object and try to send it to the NetMHC service. However to do so and start the job I have to click the submit button on the website. But instead of a result like this, http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/cgi-bin/webface2.fcgi?jobid=5824785E00001E9D3B38E362&wait=20, it always returns the html website of NetMHC. How can I add the submit command to my json object to start the job/http request?

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("SEQPASTE", "MAALPGTVPRMMRPAPGQNYPRTGFNHIRHKIV"); // <textarea name="SEQPASTE" rows=8 cols=64></textarea>
obj.put("len",9);//<select multiple name=len><option value=9>9mer peptides
  //add submit button to json
  //<input type="submit" value="Submit">

try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/services/NetMHC/"); 
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(obj.toJSONString());
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");          
    request.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

    String jsonResp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(jsonResp);

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Are there any alternative ways to send a request to a webserver which has a submit button? So far I tried cgi, but it turned out I have no permission. I also considered SOAP, but was struggeling to create a correct SOAP body that fits my query. Do you have any advice for me? Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you check out the source of the website, you should see a target-link where the button points to, just request this target-site in your code and parse the HTML that comes back.

Comment: It looks like you might be missing a couple other necessary fields as well.  I would suggest using a tool like http://www.telerik.com/fiddler to inspect the post data for the form.  It will generate web client code to help you along the way as well.